# How to get together two binary numbers in c

Tags: c, binary, int, byte, type-conversion

I am programming ***microcontrollers*** in ***C programming language***. I have an "X" function called:

```
unsigned char low_byte = spi_xfer(0);
```

That gives me: 96. In binary this is 01100000

I have another "Y" function called:

```
unsigned char high_byte = spi_xfer(0);
```

that gives me: 64. In binary this is 01000000

After that I need to right shift 3 times ***low_byte***, this would be in binary: 1100 = 12 in decimal

```
unsigned char new_value = (low_byte >> 3);
```

Now I need to get together ***new_value*** and ***high_byte*** so that I can have:

```
unsigned int raw_value;
```

Which must be equal to 01000000 1100 = 1036 in decimal

What operation do I need to make to gather these two numbers? Thanks

Comment: `(high_byte << 4) | new_value`

Comment: I can't use that operation because I need to have a binary number of 12 digits. I am not sure but I have seen in the examples that the binary OR  operation is limited to only bytes (8 digits). So I am going to lose information

Comment: "OR operation is limited to only bytes". No that's not correct. Jut try it.

Comment: But why do you left shift 4 times ***high_byte***? The one I need to right shift three times is ***low_byte***. That is because I am reading a temperature and the value is stored from the 3 bit to the 14. Considering the least significant bit of ***low_byte*** as the bit 0

Comment: Well because high_byte is `01000000` and you need that to be `01000000 0000` so that you can add in the low_byte 4 bits.

Comment: Is this solved now? If yes someone needs to post the solution as Answer. @kaylum and Delfin.

Comment: Yes this is solved now. I asked him if he wanted to post that as an answer